# How not to display posts of other users in a contributor/author post page multi-author wordpress site

Tags: wordpress

I am doing a multi author wordpress site, I dont want other users post to be displayed or listed in the post page. only the users post must be shown.
Is there a plugin for this? or is there a way to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you not just set their role as Author? This is how i've done it in the past. Also look at the definition of the Author role:

> Author - Somebody who can publish and
>   manage their own posts

Source: http://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities